# Angular 6 ng-template - best way to display or hide an image tag

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

Within my `Kendo UI Grid` `cell template`, I am trying to either display an image (if it exists) OR display the customer initials.

```html
 <kendo-grid-column>

 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
   <i class="circle" style="background: #b5b2ad; display: inline-flex; height: 30px; width: 30px;
         border-radius: 50%; border: white; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
    <span style="margin: 6px 0 0 5px; color: #000;font: 14px Arial;">
     {{ getCustomerInitials(dataItem) }}
    </span>
    <img [hidden]="noImage" src="{{ './assets/profiles/customer/' + dataItem.CustomerID + '.jpg' }}" 
     (error)="noImage=true"  
     height="30" width="30" style="border-radius:30px;"/>

   </i>
   
 </ng-template>

 </kendo-grid-column>
```

I use the Angular equivalent of the img `onrrror` event:

```
 <img [hidden]="noImage" (error)="noImage=true" src... />
```

However I believe it's setting `hidden` to true for every record.

Is there a better design for this logic - to display either the image or the custer initials ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, using `className=''` and a `margin` to push the image a little to the left to overlay the initials.

```html
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>

 <i class="circle" style="background: #b5b2ad; display: inline-flex; height: 30px; width: 30px;
       border-radius: 50%; border: white; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
  <span style="margin: 6px 0 0 5px; color: #000;font: 14px Arial;">
   {{ getCustomerInitials(dataItem) }}
  </span>
  <img src="{{ './assets/profiles/customers/' + dataItem.CustomerID + '.jpg' }}" 
   [class.cust-verified]="dataItem.IsVerified"
   onerror="this.style.display='none'; this.className='' "
   (error)="noImage=true"
   height="30" width="30" style="border-radius:30px; margin: -1px 0 0 -23px;" 
   alt="Customer Image"/>
 </i>
 
</ng-template>
```